# How to change double hyphen to single hyphen of file names?

Tags: command-line, files, rename

I have been using the `rename` command to get control over my naming conventions across my system. In converting spaces in file names to hyphens, I have inadvertently created consecutive hyphens in some file names. These are proving difficult to remedy using the rename command.

I have tried unsuccessfully with several different iterations of the following:

```
rename 's/--/-/g'
```

I do understand that double hyphens are reserved for end of arguments but a backslash escape doesn't seem to work here and I'm out of other ideas.

I am relatively new to command line processing so your patience is appreciated.

Comment: What was wrong with `rename 's/--/-/g'`? did you get error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To squash multiple hyphens (one hyphen followed by one or more hyphens) into a single one for all files in the current directory use:

```
rename 's/--+/-/g' -- *
```

The `--` is important if files start with a hyphen, otherwise they would be interpreted as command line arguments. The `*` expands to the list of files in the current directory.

Comment: What does the **+** do? Just so I have a better understanding and possibly solve similar issues going forward. That worked like a champ by the way!

Comment: It matches one or more of the preceding expression (the character `-`).